Replace DLL by an older version
I use a nuget package that references a DLL that is version 2.0.0.0.
I want to replace this DLL with version 1.5.0.0 but when I re-run the program, the DLL is automatically replaced with version 2.0.0.0
How can I make version 1.5.0.0 permanent?
Thank's for your help.
